# SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token with @import in .less file during npm start

Tags: reactjs, webpack, less

This is a React app created using create-react-app (CRA) using antd (Ant Design). Existing project has been modified in attempt to server-side-rendering (SSR).

`npm run build` works just fine.

After that is when the error occurs. On `npm start`:

```
/Users/user/dev/reactappname/node_modules/antd/lib/style/index.less:1
@import './themes/index';
^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
```

It's possible it's a webpack issue, but I'm not certain.

webpack.config.server.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  entry: './server.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'server.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.less']
  },
  target: 'node',
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    rules: [
{
    test: /\.less$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'style-loader'
        }, {
            loader: 'css-loader'
        },
        {
            loader: 'less-loader',
            options: {
                javascriptEnabled: true
            }
        }]
},
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        exclude: [/\.js$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
          publicPath: '/',
          emitFile: false,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
        [ "babel-plugin-transform-require-ignore",
          {
            "extensions": [".less", ".sass"]
          }],
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "babel-plugin-root-import",
        ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "style": true}]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your webpack.config file?

Comment: @Scurgery added webpack.config.server.js above

Answer (score 0):

This is webpack config for the server, so you need to emit your css/less/sass files to build/css by using MiniCssExtractPlugin in your webpack. Then on server-side, inject  scripts that point to the css/less/sass files in build/css.

E.g. webpack config for plain css (you would need to add less support in your case)

```
{
  test: /\.(css|less)$/i,
  use: [
    {
      loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
    },
    {
      loader: 'css-loader'
    },
    {
      loader: 'less-loader',
      options: {
        javascriptEnabled: true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Let's assume this webpack would emit this file `build/css/main.css`. Then, your server.js looks like this:

```
app.use("*", (req, res) => {
  let htmlData = fs.readFileSync("build/index.html", "utf8");
  const cssData = fs.readFileSync("build/css/main.css", "utf8");
  htmlData = htmlData.replace("</head>", `<style>${cssData}</style></head>`);
});
```

You will need to configure more for LESS if this is not enough for it to work.